# 次のクラスへの値の渡し方

Tags: java

クラス`getTime()`で勤務日数`N`、１日の作業開始時間`st`、終業時間`et`を入力する。それらの値を次のクラス`divWage()`へ持っていって計算に使いたいが上手くいかない。クラスの理解が十分でないと考えられるので、ご教示賜りたい。

**現状のコード:**

```
public int [][] getTime(){
    System.out.println("勤務日数Nを入力する 　例：5");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt(); 
    String d = sc.nextLine();

    int [][] time = new int [N][2];
    for(int j = 0;j<N;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k<2;k++){
            time [j][k] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        st = time[j][0];
        et = time[j][1];
        divWage(st,et);
    }
    return time;
}

public void divWage(int s,int e){
    s = st;
    e = et;

}・・・
```

Answer (score 2):

ソースコードを拝読したところ、うまくいかない原因が複数あるように見受けられます。
もしかしたらJavaの構文全体についての知識が整理できていないのかもしれません。

下記をご確認の上、教材のテキストなどがありましたら読み返してみてください。
質問を加筆修正して、具体的に何が分からないのかを明確にすると的確な回答を得やすくなります。

- `getTime()`と`divWave()`はクラスではなくメソッドです。
  コンパイルエラーが発生しても良いので、`public class Hoge`などの構文で記述されているクラスを省略せずに[再現可能な短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)の形式で記述してください。
- `st = time[j][0];`や`s = st;`などで変数の型が定義されていません。
  メソッド内で初めて変数を宣言する場合は、`int st = time[j][0];`のように変数の型を定義しないと「`st`って何それ？食べ物？」とコンパイラが混乱してしまいます。
  もしも[メンバ変数](https://www.javadrive.jp/start/member/index1.html)として`st`などを定義している場合は、質問文を編集してその情報を補完してください。
- `divWage`メソッドの引数と戻り値は正しいですか？
  ご質問のコードでは、例えばメソッドの引数で`s`を渡していますが、即座に`s = st;`のような代入が発生し、渡された`s`がどこにも利用されていません。
  そして`public void divWage`は戻り値が存在しない`void`で定義されているので、計算後の数値を`return`できません。
  もしも`st`と`et`を受け取り、戻り値として小数を返したい場合は`public double divWage(int st, int et)`のように定義します。

Answer (score 2):

(直接の回答ではないですが、遠回りになりそうに見えたので)

既に付いている回答に書かれている指摘も妥当なものですが、より重要でかつ質問者がすぐできることは、

> 上手くいかない。

の内容を具体的に質問文に追記することです。

- どういう数値を入力したのか
- その結果、動作としてどうなることを期待していたのか
- 実際の結果は(期待に反して)どうなったのか

  - 何かエラーが出たのならエラーメッセージはどんなものだったか

用語の誤りや不完全なコードについては(例えば↓のように)ある程度読者が補完することが可能です。
また質問者からすると、困難で修正するのに時間がかかる場合もあるでしょう。

一方、正しく用語が用いられ実行可能なコードが提示されていても上記の情報が無ければ回答不能なことも少なくないです。

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    private int st;
    private int et;

    public int [][] getTime(){
        System.out.println("勤務日数Nを入力する 　例：5");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        String d = sc.nextLine();

        int [][] time = new int [N][2];
        for(int j = 0;j<N;j++){
            for(int k = 0;k<2;k++){
                time [j][k] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            st = time[j][0];
            et = time[j][1];
            divWage(st,et);
        }
        return time;
    }

    public void divWage(int s,int e){
        s = st;
        e = et;

        System.out.printf("%d, %d\n",s,e);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new App().getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問者の「上手くいかない」事象を再現しようとしたが、読者が補完してもまだ不十分な情報があると感じれば改めて情報を要求することになります。(もちろん初めから十分な情報が提示できているのが望ましい、というのはその通りですが)

Comment: 日ごろから忙しくされている皆さんの手間を取らせることを申し訳なく思ってます（このコメ欄改行ができない！）。メンドーならうっちゃって頂いても構いませんので。話を戻します。例えば、勤務日数２日とし、勤務時間帯を入力します。→ cmd上で9 16(改行)12 16(9時から16時)(12時から16時)。今のところ、次のクラスへ値が移るのは12 16のみで、その値を元にその日の分の（アルバイトの）給料が計算されてしまいます。求めたいのは２日分の給料ですが、最後のデータだけ次のクラスへ移ってしまって、それを元に計算される状況です。これまでいろいろやってきたのですが、これまで求めている事に最も近い結果が得られたのはtime[j][k]を条件付けているfor文の中で全て処理を済ませた場合です。あと、クラスについてですが、皆さんのご指摘どおり、戻り値、引数、修飾子等について理解不足な部分があります。それについてはご容赦の程、お願います。